# Convert string with space to json

Tags: java, android, json

I've problem with text which i got it as server response. I want to write it down to shared preferences. But it throws exception because of there are white space and some key with empty value.

**Name=Ali K,picture=,**

```
    String jsonStr="{IsEmailSubscription=true, Name=Ali K,picture=, 
Id=2534, Surname=Murat, Email=Email}";

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    settings.edit().putString(SharedText.Customer.toString(),obj.toString()).commit();
```

what do you suggest....?

EDIT 1:

```
  org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 39 of 

{IsEmailSubscription=true, Name=Ahmet k, Id=2534, Surname=Kosen, 

MobilePhone=5363481189, Email=Email}
```

Server returns me string but i need to convert it to 
JSON, todo this i use JSONObject.

Comment: your `jsonStr` is not a JSON

Comment: could you provide stacktrace?

Comment: Any string in JSON must be enclosed by the `"` character. See [JSON.org](http://json.org/). In your example, you'd have to insert `\"` so it doesn't end `jsonStr`.

Comment: What server has given you this invalid-json response?

Comment: firstly, thanks for your reply. I am getting a string from server and need to put this tring to shared preferences, then i need to read id again. For example i need name value of this string. How can i do that without converting string to JSON or hashmap ?

Comment: Why don't you ask your API team to change it with valid format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are defining two problems:

1. Your JSON format is not correct as pointed by others.
2. For getting optional fields from JSON object, you can use `optInt`, `optString` kind of API present in JSONObject.
   Correct format of your json string should be:

   String jsonStr="{IsEmailSubscription=true, Name='Ali K',picture='', Id=2534, Surname=Murat, Email=Email}";

Comment: This is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is invalid, what server are you getting this from? Your own?

It should be something like this:

```
String jsonStr="{\"IsEmailSubscription\": true, \"Name\": \"Ali K\", \"picture\": \"\", \"Id\": 2534, \"Surname\": \"Murat\", \"Email\": \"Email\"}";
```

Comment: This is not a valid json. The keys should be inside quotes.